# Change Column Name and Cell Value Pgfplotstable

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable, columns, csv, cell

I have this csv file:

```
,Accuracy
1,0.982
2,0.982
3,0.982
4,0.988
5,0.916
6,0.976
7,0.958
8,0.97
9,0.945
10,0.988
11,0.969
```

This is the screenshot when I imported it into Latex file:

[image]

This is the working example file:

```
\documentclass[a4,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}


    \begin{table}[h!]
        \caption{Accuracy value}
        \label{tab:cvinitial}
        \begin{center}
            \pgfplotstabletypeset[
            col sep=comma,
            header = has colnames,
            string type,
            display columns/ /.style={column type={|l|},}
            display columns/Accuracy/.style={column type={|l|}},
            every head row/.style={before row=\hline,after row=\hline},
            every nth row={1}{before row=\hline},
            every last row/.style={after row=\hline},
            ]{
            ,Accuracy
            1,0.982
            2,0.982
            3,0.982
            4,0.988
            5,0.916
            6,0.976
            7,0.958
            8,0.97
            9,0.945
            10,0.988
            11,0.969
        }
        \end{center}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

I have several questions:

1. How can I change the first column name from `0` to another value/text, for example `No`?
2. How can I change the last element of the first column name (11) to another value/text, for example `Average`?
3. How do I add vertical line between columns?

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

1. To change the predefined value of this empty cell `0` to `No`, I added played with `assign column name`. (I am not claiming it is necessarily the most elegant way.)
2. To add a vertical bar, I played with `every even column` and `every odd column`.
3. To replace the element of the table, I added `every row 10 column 0/.style={postproc cell content/.style={@cell content=Average}},`

```
\documentclass[a4,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}


    \begin{table}[h!]
        \caption{Accuracy value}
        \label{tab:cvinitial}
        \begin{center}
            \pgfplotstabletypeset[
            col sep=comma,
            header=has colnames,
            assign column name/.style={
            /pgfplots/table/column name={\ifx#10
            No
            \else
            #1
            \fi}
            },
            string type,
            %display columns/ /.style={column type={|l|},}
            every odd column/.style={
                column type/.add={}{|}
            },
            every even column/.style={
                column type/.add={|}{|}
            },
            every row 10 column 0/.style={postproc cell content/.style={@cell
            content=Average}},
            every head row/.style={before row=\hline,after row=\hline},
            every nth row={1}{before row=\hline},
            every last row/.style={after row=\hline},
            ]{
            ,Accuracy
            1,0.982
            2,0.982
            3,0.982
            4,0.988
            5,0.916
            6,0.976
            7,0.958
            8,0.97
            9,0.945
            10,0.988
            11,0.969
        }
        \end{center}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I got this error `Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, 'compat=1.16' is unknown in this context. Please use at most 'compat=1.15'. \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}`  @marmot

Comment: @AkhmadZaki This just means you do not run the most recent version of pgfplotstable. The above code works fine with `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}` or without `\pgfplotsset{compat=...}`.

Comment: yes, it works, but how about changing the value `11` in the first column and adding vertical line between columns @marmot ?

Comment: @AkhmadZaki I added these things.

Comment: The vertical line at the left and the right side of the table still not showing. How to add it ?

Comment: @AkhmadZaki I followed your instruction "How do I add vertical line between columns?".....

Comment: I'm sorry, but I also I need to add the vertical line at the left and right of the table @marmot